# AndroidStudio3 / Android Emulator doesn't enable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to create a simple HelloWorld application for Android using Android Studio 3.0.1. I am trying to Run the application using virtual "Pixel" device. When Android Emulator starts, it stucks on the loading screen for infinity, and this appears in the console:

`11/25 14:21:34: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.`

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem.But Now it's working fine. You can solve it by "Wipe Data" option in AVD Manager.

[image: Clear Data of Virtual Device]

One of the following action can solve your problem.
   -

- Wipe Data in AVD Manager

  - Check your AVD settings are proper or not.
  - If your computer has Intel processor then install or update HAXM.
  - Wait at least 5-10 minutes as the first run of Virtual Device take a lot of time.